# Не справляюсь с цепочечной командой "lods" на языке ассемблера

Tags: ассемблер, dos

Цель - подсчитать произведение элементов в строках с использованием цепочечных команд.

```
masm
model small

.data
    matr dw 1,2,3
         dw 4,5,6
         dw 7,8,9
    n dw 3
    comp dw ?

.stack 256

.code
    main proc
        assume ds:@data,es:@data

        mov ax,@data
        mov ds,ax
        mov es,ax

        mov cx,n
        LO:
            ; установка si на начало текущей строки
            mov ax,n
            sub ax,cx
            mul n
            mov bx,ax
            add bx,bx
            mov si,matr[bx]

            ; подсчёт произведения
            push cx
            mov cx,n
            cld
            mov comp,1
            LI:
                lodsw
                mul comp
                mov comp,ax
            loop LI

            ; вывод результата
            mov ax,comp
            mov bx,10
            mov cx,0
            L1:
                xor dx,dx
                div bx
                push dx
                inc cx
            cmp ax,0
            jg L1
            mov ah,2h
            L2:
                pop dx
                add dl,30h
                int 21h
            loop L2
            mov dl,' '
            int 21h

            pop cx
        loop LO

        mov ax,4C00h
        int 21h
    main endp

end main
```

Проблема в том, что в результате выводятся непонятные значения, в данном случае "0 60 0". Путём тестов удалось выяснить что проблема лежит только лишь в части кода под комментарием "подсчёт произведения". Вроде как правильно применяю команду да и все нужные действия перед циклом делаю, но работать правильно она не хочет. Может быть, здесь мне укажут на мою ошибку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в команде `mov si, matr[bx]`. Для команды `lods` нужно, чтобы в `si` находилось смещение ячейки памяти (в данном случае первоначально должен записываться адрес начала строки двумерного массива), но команда `mov si, matr[bx]` записывает в `si` не адрес ячейки памяти, а значение этой ячейки. `mov` нужно заменить на `lea`:

```
lea si,matr[bx]
```